# Is it possible to change the Dock icon of an app so it remains when it is not running?

Tags: cocoa, macos, icons, dock

Is it possible to badge a dock icon and have the icon persist when the application is quit? iCal does this, but I have not seen it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snow Leopard introduced an official [dock tile plug-in](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/CreatingaDockTilePlug-in/CreatingaDockTilePlug-in.html) API for this. In Leopard [it’s possible](http://jens.ayton.se/blag/the-mysteries-of-ical-revealed/) to piggyback on iCal’s mechanism, but I don’t recommend it.